# Why does my Tokio server listening for UDP packets use 100% CPU until its OOM killed?

Tags: multithreading, networking, rust, udp, rust-tokio

I am listening to udp packets. Once the first packet arrives, I start to listen for more packets. If one packet is received, then the server will start to run fullspeed (even though there should be a delay), and eventually gets killed:

```rs
//! server.rs
use std::net::SocketAddr;
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::net::UdpSocket;
use tokio::{sync::mpsc, task, time}; // 1.4.0
use std::env;
use std::sync::Arc;

const UDP_HEADER: usize = 8;
const IP_HEADER: usize = 20;
const AG_HEADER: usize = 4;
const MAX_DATA_LENGTH: usize = (64 * 1024 - 1) - UDP_HEADER - IP_HEADER;
const MAX_CHUNK_SIZE: usize = MAX_DATA_LENGTH - AG_HEADER;
const MAX_DATAGRAM_SIZE: usize = 0x10000;
const ADDRESS: &str = "127.0.0.1:8080";
const ADDRESS_CLIENT: &str = "127.0.0.1:8000";

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    server().await;
}

async fn server() {
    eprintln!("Starting the server");
    let addr = env::args().nth(1).unwrap_or_else(|| ADDRESS.to_string());
    let socket = UdpSocket::bind(&addr).await.unwrap();
    let arc = Arc::new(socket);
    let mut buf = [0u8; MAX_DATA_LENGTH];
    let (debounce_tx, mut debounce_rx) = mpsc::channel::<Vec<u8>>(MAX_DATAGRAM_SIZE);

    let _debouncer = task::spawn(async move {
        let mut _packet_ids: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
        _packet_ids = vec![0; 10];
        let duration = Duration::from_millis(1300);

        loop {
            match time::timeout(duration, debounce_rx.recv()).await {
                Ok(Some(bytes)) => {
                    let id: u8 = bytes.clone()[0];
                    _packet_ids[id as usize] = 1;
                    eprintln!("{} id packet received:{:?}", id, _packet_ids);
                    if _packet_ids.iter().all(|x| x == &1i32) {
                        println!("All packets have been received, stop program ");
                     //   break;
                    }
                }
                Ok(None) => {
                    eprintln!("Done: {:?}", _packet_ids);
                    break;
                }
                Err(_) => {
                    eprintln!("No activity for 1.3sd");
                }
            }
        }
    });
    // Listen for first packet
    let result = arc.clone().recv_from(&mut buf).await;
    match result {
        Ok((len, addr)) => {
            eprintln!("Bytes len: {} from {}", len, addr);
            debounce_tx
                .send(buf.to_vec())
                .await
                .expect("Unable to talk to debounce");
        }
        Err(_) => {
            eprintln!("Couldnt get datagram");
        }
    }
    // listen for other packets
    loop {
        let thread_socket = arc.clone();
        let _server = task::spawn({
            let debounce_tx = debounce_tx.clone();

            async move {
                while let result = thread_socket.recv_from(&mut buf).await {
                    match result {
                        Ok((len, addr)) => {
                            eprintln!("Bytes len: {} from {}", len, addr);
                            debounce_tx
                                .send(buf.to_vec())
                                .await
                                .expect("Unable to talk to debounce");
                        }
                        Err(_) => {
                            eprintln!("Couldnt get datagram");
                        }
                    }
                 }
                 // Prevent deadlocks
                 drop(debounce_tx);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```rs
//! client.rs
async fn client() {
    eprintln!("Starting the client");

    let remote_addr: SocketAddr = env::args()
        .nth(2)
        .unwrap_or_else(|| ADDRESS.into()) // cargo run --example udp-client -- 127.0.0.1:8080
        .parse()
        .unwrap();

    // We use port 0 to let the operating system allocate an available port for us.
    let local_addr: SocketAddr = if remote_addr.is_ipv4() {
        ADDRESS_CLIENT // "0.0.0.0:0" //
    } else {
        "[::]:0"
    }
    .parse()
    .unwrap();
    let socket = UdpSocket::bind(ADDRESS_CLIENT).await.unwrap();

    socket.connect(&remote_addr).await.unwrap();

    socket.send(&[0, 2, 3]).await.expect("Unable to talk to network");
    socket.send(&[1, 2, 3]).await.expect("Unable to talk to network");
    time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1200)).await;
    socket.send(&[2, 2, 3]).await.expect("Unable to talk to network");
    socket.send(&[3, 2, 3]).await.expect("Unable to talk to network");
    socket.send(&[4, 2, 3]).await.expect("Unable to talk to network");
    socket.send(&[5, 2, 3]).await.expect("Unable to talk to network");
    socket.send(&[6, 2, 3]).await.expect("Unable to talk to network");
    socket.send(&[7, 2, 3]).await.expect("Unable to talk to network");
    time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1200)).await;
    socket.send(&[8, 2, 3]).await.expect("Unable to talk to network");
    time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(3200)).await;
    socket.send(&[9, 2, 3]).await.expect("Unable to talk to network"); // stop when n1 = 0

    eprintln!("Client done");
}
```

I'm sending 10 packets from the client where first byte range from 0 to 9. I am just trying to make it work for now, I am aware of the buffer overflow. Here's the server output:

```
Starting the server
Bytes len: 3 from 127.0.0.1:8000
0 id packet received:[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Bytes len: 3 from 127.0.0.1:8000
1 id packet received:[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Bytes len: 3 from 127.0.0.1:8000
Bytes len: 3 from 127.0.0.1:8000
Bytes len: 3 from 127.0.0.1:8000
Bytes len: 3 from 127.0.0.1:8000
Bytes len: 3 from 127.0.0.1:8000
Bytes len: 3 from 127.0.0.1:8000
2 id packet received:[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
3 id packet received:[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
4 id packet received:[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
5 id packet received:[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
6 id packet received:[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
7 id packet received:[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
Bytes len: 3 from 127.0.0.1:8000
8 id packet received:[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
No activity for 1.3sd
No activity for 1.3sd
Bytes len: 3 from 127.0.0.1:8000
9 id packet received:[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
All packets have been received, stop program 
No activity for 1.3sd
No activity for 1.3sd
No activity for 1.3sd
Killed
```

How do I keep the server running smoothly without being killed?

Comment: You're calling `task::spawn` in a loop, without awaiting anything, which means that it's going to spawn a background thread, and immediately repeat the loop, spawning another background task, and spawning new tasks at full speed. I'd expect that it would continue doing this until the spawned tasks take up all the memory and the process is killed due to that.

Comment: @Frxstream, I perfectly know this, but I don't know how to correct it. Without the loop the server doesnt stay awake

Comment: What if you removed the task::spawn() and just used the while loop that .awaits on recv_from()?  (You could also .await the JoinHandle that is returned by tokio::spawn() in order to wait until that task is done before continuing, but I don't think you need to use spawn here)

Comment: If I remove task::spawn doesnt it defeat the purpose of having a multithreaded server? (just asking)

Comment: In this case, you're using udp to respond to single message requests, so multithreading doesn't provide much benefit.  Udp is connectionless, so you wont need a thread per connection, and you've only got one socket open, so you can only receive one message at a time.  If each request took a long time to process and respond to, you could spawn a task to handle the request after it's received, but request are often short lived and the overhead of using more than one thread (as opposed to using single threaded async) might not be worth it

Comment: So how could I open a new socket when socket is already busy and a new packet is received?

Comment: You'd have to be using TCP to open a new socket once a connection is received, but in that case, you would be awaiting on accept() in your main server loop and once a new connection is received and a socket is created, you can spawn a new task to handle that connection.  With UDP you only have one socket and received packets will be queued until read one at a time (although you can process the messages concurrently by spawning after the messages is received, as mentioned before).  This is a limitation of the OS and socket interface

Comment: Thank you @transistor, that's a very interesting explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it thanks to @Frxstrem and @transistor's comments, see code's comment for the change:

```c
 loop {
        let thread_socket = arc.clone();
        let debounce_tx = debounce_tx.clone(); // moved up
       /* let _server = task::spawn({
            async move { */
                if let result = thread_socket.recv_from(&mut buf).await { // previously while
                    match result {
                        Ok((len, addr)) => {
                            eprintln!("Bytes len: {} from {}", len, addr);
                            debounce_tx
                                .send(buf.to_vec())
                                .await
                                .expect("Unable to talk to debounce");
                        }
                        Err(_) => {
                            eprintln!("Couldnt get datagram");
                        }
                    }
                 }
                 // Prevent deadlocks
                 drop(debounce_tx);
         /*   }
        }); */
    }
```